# Return value of FindOne mongoose nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Alright, I'm banging my head after trying this code in 50 different ways.

So I have sample game which is played 2v2, in every game Schema the players are referenced to the user and by their username.

Now in the game, I want to take the ratings from these users and update them accordingly, this has to happen at the same time.

I can't seem to get my hands on my user objects (coming from long time Java, so some of this just straight up doesn't make sense).

If possible, I'd like to expand this, so a huge nested bunch of code is not what I'm looking for.

Without further blabbering:

gameSchema:

```
var gameSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    teamA_player1:      { type: String, ref: "userModel", required: true},
    teamA_player2:      { type: String, ref: "userModel", required: true},
    teamB_player1:      { type: String, ref: "userModel", required: true},
    teamB_player2:      { type: String, ref: "userModel", required: true},
    teamA_score:        { type: Number, required: true},
    teamB_score:        { type: Number, required: true}, 
    author:             { type: String, ref: "userModel", required: true},
    verification:       [{ type: String, ref: "userModel", required: true}],
    verified:           { type: Boolean},
    timestamp:          { type: Date}
});
```

userSchema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username:       { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password:       { type: String, required: true},
    firstName:      { type: String},
    lastName:       { type: String},
    about:          { type: String},
    email:          { type: String},
    clubs:          { type: [{type: ObjectId, ref: "clubModel"}]},
    games:          { type: [{type: ObjectId, ref: "gameModel"}]}, 
    rating:         { type: Number}
});
```

The issue with my code in my gameController:

```
updateRating = function(game){

    // The following code blob doesn't work and calling a_1.rating just gives Nan / undefined.
    var a_1 = users.findOne({username: game.teamA_player1});
    var a_2 = users.findOne({username: game.teamA_player2});
    var b_1 = users.findOne({username: game.teamB_player1});
    var b_2 = users.findOne({username: game.teamB_player2});

    var a_rating_old = (a_1.rating+a_2.rating)/2;
    var b_rating_old = (b_1.rating+b_2.rating)/2;

    var a_rating_new = 0;
    var b_rating_new = 0;

    if(game.teamA_score>game.teamB_score){
        a_rating_new = ratingChange(a_rating_old, b_rating_old, true);
        b_rating_new = ratingChange(b_rating_old, a_rating_old, false);
    }else{
        a_rating_new = ratingChange(a_rating_old, b_rating_old, false);
        b_rating_new = ratingChange(b_rating_old, a_rating_old, true);
    }

    var a_rating_change = a_rating_new - a_rating_old;
    var b_rating_change = b_rating_new - b_rating_old;

    a_1.rating += Math.round(a_rating_change * (a_rating_old/a_1.rating));
    a_2.rating += Math.round(a_rating_change * (a_rating_old/a_2.rating));
    b_1.rating += Math.round(b_rating_change * (b_rating_old/b_1.rating));
    b_2.rating += Math.round(b_rating_change * (b_rating_old/b_2.rating));

    a_1.save();
    a_2.save();
    b_1.save();
    b_2.save();

}
```

So basically I'm wondering what the correct way would be to acquire my users here, extract their ratings, update it and then save the users with the new ratings (game itself doesn't undergo any changes).

Code can also all be found here: https://github.com/mathieudevos/pinkiponki

Answer (score 0):

So asuming you already required the model in that **user** variable the thing you a re doing wrong is that you are assigning that function to a variable (ex. a_1) when in reallity you need to pass a callback function and then assign the user that that callback recives to the variable.

Something like this:

```
user.findOne({username: game.teamA_player1}, function(err, user){
  if(err) throw err;
  a_1 = user;
});
```

I'd recomend you change the variable's name in which you require the model from user to User.

You can see that the callback function I'm passing has an error object and a user object, this last one is where your info is stored, the object from the db, so you should assign its value to the variable you want, in this case a_1.

Please tell me if it worked out!

Comment: This limits my a_1 to within the function, making me unable to use it outside of the function(err, user){ //code and var goes here }. 

I want to reveal it to my updateRating function, work with the ratings there and update them there.

Comment: You'd need to declare the variable outside.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, seems I had quite a few wrong ideas while attempting this issue.

The main issue is that I was not considering the fact that all of the db queries run async, which caused a huge hassle.

Now option A is to nest it all together, which ends up a huge code-blob/spaghetti, not really a fan of that. Especially because it's not very nice if I want to continue writing on this application.

So to option b, install the module deasync and just #DealWithIt

Code is now as follows:

```
var done = 0;

var a_1;
var a_2;
var b_1;
var b_2;

users.findOne({username: game.teamA_player1}, function(err, usera1){
    if(usera1)
        a_1 = usera1.rating;
    done += 1;
});
users.findOne({username: game.teamA_player2}, function(err, usera2){
    if(usera2)
        a_2 = usera2.rating;
    done += 1;
});
users.findOne({username: game.teamB_player1}, function(err, userb1){
    if(userb1)
        b_1 = userb1.rating;
    done += 1;
});
users.findOne({username: game.teamB_player2}, function(err, userb2){
    if(userb2)
        b_2 = userb2.rating;
    done += 1;
});

//Keep looping on deasync until we find all 4
require('deasync').loopWhile(function(){return (done!=4);});

if(a_1 == undefined || a_2 == undefined || b_1 == undefined || b_2 == undefined){
    // could not find a user probably
    log('Value undefined, error');
    return;
}
```